# Find context name in Railo/Jetty application code?

Tags: jetty, railo

I create my contexts by dropping [myname].xml files in the contexts/ directory but in my CFML code I want to dynamically find the value of [myname], ie the name of the context/webapp (or failing that the filename of the xml file or the original value of the resourceBase property before path translation occurs).

I can get data about the context (like the array of virtualhosts) using the object returned from `getPageContext().getConfig().getServletContext().getContextHandler().getCurrentWebAppContext()` but if the context name is in there I haven't worked out how to get at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getDisplayName](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ContextHandler.html#getDisplayName%28%29) on that object you have?

It defaults to null (would be useful if it was the filename), but you can specify it in the context XML file with `<Set name="DisplayName">bob</Set>`

(If you have lots of XML files to deal with, do a script to loop through each file and plonk that with the filename inside the Configure tag.)

Comment: Awesome., thanks. `getDisplayName()` was actually the first thing I tried, I assumed it would be set to a useful default but as you say I got a NULL and figured it was for something else.